# Fade in/fade out text with canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas, graphics, bitmap

I am wondering what is the best approach for adding animation to a graphics paint object on a canvas. In my case, what is the best way to fadein/fadeout text that is being drawn on a canvas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would personally keep redrawing the canvas with your Paint with alpha of 0 or less opacity. Start with an opaque color, and then put into a loop the color becoming less opaque, increasing the alpha slowly to 0.0f (transparent) or 1.0f. Color/Paint does have an alpha parameter I believe.

```
 Color color = new Color(1, 0, 0, alpha);
```

You could simply put this in a loop and do a += 0.05f on alpha variable and it'd make it look like it was becoming more or less opaque. You could put it in a concurrent async task or in some sort of Timer.

Comment: I used a variation of your idea but I got it to work thanks a lot.